# How to use Cyrillic in react-pdf?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I have tried to use [cmaps](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/blob/master/README.md). But still, it is producing non readable characters.

Answer (score 7):

> Note : react-pdf only supports .ttf format only [ by now ]

```
Font.register({
  family: "Roboto",
  src:
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ink/3.1.10/fonts/Roboto/roboto-medium-webfont.ttf"
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myText : {
    fontFamily : "Roboto"
  }
})
```